# Bootstrap Button dynamically through Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, button, twitter-bootstrap

I need to add button dynamically to the div , the button value is retrieved from  var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");

So , Please suggest me the solution

```
<div class="span12" id="btndiv" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>

function drop(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
   // Add Button here to div -btndiv

 <button class="btn btn-danger" data-jqui-type="" name="" type="submit"><i class="icon-close icon-white"></i> **data**</button>
    }
```

Comment: You want to add the button or just give the existing button a value?

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
$("<input/>").attr({type: "button", value: data}).appendTo("#btndiv");
```

Comment: How can I add CSS for this one

Comment: Add a class to this, and create a CSS class, example CSS class of `test`, then `.attr({"class":"test"})`

Answer (score 0):

```
function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text"),
        btn  = $('<button />', {'class':'btn btn-danger', 
                                 text: data,
                                 name: '',
                                 type: 'submit',
                                'data-jqui-type':''
                               }),
          i  = $('<i />', {'class':'icon-close icon-white'});

    $('#btndiv').append(btn.prepend(i));
}
```

Comment: i  = $('<i />', {'class':'icon-close icon-white'} is not adding to the button

Comment: @ineffablep - It does add the icon, but there is no icon-close as far as I know. Changing the icon class makes it work -> http://jsfiddle.net/b4Dj5/

Comment: Here are all the available icons and their names -> http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/base-css.html#icons